# Retrieve JSON from Firebase Realtime Database Using C++

Tags: c++, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Firebase C++ SDK (on desktop) to retrieve data from the realtime database. I want to store some parts of the database on the client but I can only get a `firebase::Variant`. I would just like to store the json that belongs to the data path as a file.

I could iterate over the data and generate json from that, but that seems to be a lot of overkil as the data is retrieved from json in the first place.

Is there a way to retrieve the json itself (as text), instead of querying the values and children from `firebase::database::DataSnapshot`?

Kind regards,
Jeroen